# Cannot find glitch in program using recursion for multible nested for-loops

Tags: python, recursion, nested-loops

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

endlist = []

def loopfunc(n, lis):
    if n ==0:
        endlist.append(lis[0]+lis[1]+lis[2]+lis[3]+lis[4])
    
    for i in alphabet:
        if n >0:
            lis.append(i)
            loopfunc(n-1, lis )

loopfunc(5, [])
```

This program is supposed to make endlist be:

```
endlist = [aaaaa, aaaab, aaaac, ... zzzzy, zzzzz]
```

But it makes it:

```
endlist = [aaaaa, aaaaa, aaaaa, ... , aaaaa]
```

The lenght is right, but it won't make different words. Can anyone help me see why?

Comment: Your `i` never gets incremented in the inner loop, so I don't see how you can expect mixed letter words.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you ever add to `endlist` is the first 5 elements of `lis`, and since you have a single `lis` that is shared among all the recursive calls (note that you never create a new list in this code other than the initial values for `endlist` and `lis`, so every append to `lis` is happening to the same list), those first 5 elements are always the `a` values that you appended in your first 5 recursive calls.  The rest of the alphabet goes onto the end of `lis` and is never reached by any of your other code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want string in the end, it's a little easier just to use strings for collecting your items. This avoids the possibility of shared mutable references which is cause your issues. With that the recursion becomes pretty concise:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def loopfunc(n, lis=""):
    if n < 1:
        return  [lis] 
    res = []
    for a in alphabet:
        res.extend(loopfunc(n-1, lis + a))
    return res

l = loopfunc(5)

print(l[0], l[1], l[-1], l[-2])
# aaaaa aaaab zzzzz zzzzy
```

Note that with n=5 you'll have almost 12 million combinations. If you plan on having larger `n` values, it may be worth rewriting this as a generator.